# Mailchimp Campaign doesnt display images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rss, mailchimp

My xml is like this

```
  <title></title>
  <description></description>
  <pubDate></pubDate>
  <media:content url="https://ymimg.b8cdn.com/uploads/article/3422/pictures/2649911/18425525_10154828390294862_1789009504724824198_n.jpg" type="image/jpg" medium="image"/>
```

Mailchimp displays all titles,desicription and date etc fine but not displaying image .

Is I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/images-videos-files/troubleshooting-images-in-campaigns) is useful to troubleshoot images in campaigns, hopeful it's helpful.